# How to change value of /GrpPwd/ Cell in all Rows?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I need to perform this SQL Query:

```
UPDATE Resurses SET GrpPwd = @GrpPwd1 WHERE Resurs = @Resurs1
```

For all rows in my Access Database using VB.NET
How can i do it?

I use this code but id doesn't work:

Password Generator:

```
 Dim charset As String = nalf
    Dim r As New Random()
    Dim lenPass As Integer = r.Next(minLength, maxLength)
    Dim str As String = String.Empty
    For i As Integer = 0 To lenPass - 1
        str += charset(r.Next(0, charset.Length))
    Next
    Return str
End Function
```

Update rows

```
If DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(3).Value = "Yes" Then
        nres = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value
        nalf = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(6).Value
        nsym = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(1).Value
        Dim parol1 As String
        Dim pwd As String = pass99(nsym, nsym) '
        parol1 = pwd
        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand()
        Dim Conn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.oledb.12.0; Data source=" + bpath) 
        cmd.Connection = Conn
        Conn.Open()
        For i As Integer = 0 To k - 1

            cmd.CommandText = String.Format("UPDATE Resurses SET GrpPwd = @GrpPwd1{0} WHERE Resurs = @Resurs1{0};", i)

            cmd.Parameters.Add(String.Format("@GrpPwd1{0}", i), OleDbType.WChar).Value = parol1
            cmd.Parameters.Add(String.Format("@Resurs1{0}", i), OleDbType.Integer).Value = nres
        Next
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Conn.Close()
        MsgBox("All rows are updated!")
    End If
```

f

Comment: I don't fully get what the question is... you have 1 table 'Resurses' with one field 'GrpPwd' and one field 'Resurs' and you want to update to what? I'd rephrase the question, in order to clarify what the actual problem is and  to get a precise answer

Comment: use the edit link below the question

Comment: Yes. I've 1 table /Resurses/ with fields /Resurses/ - resource name, /GrpPwd/ - resource password, /Alphabet/ - list of chars,  which i use to generate password.

When i press button /Change password/, i need to change /GrpPwd/ value for each row in Table to new password, which generated from symbols in /Alphabet/ field for each resource.

I just don't know how to do it in Access via VB.NET

Comment: look up the ID of the row ... schema F: update table set field where id = @id

Comment: ID as in the primary key... if you want to change the rows one by one.... if not update table set field = @newvalue .... no where clause

Comment: Screen http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/uploads/monthly_03_2015/post-654231-142665901471.png

Comment: I see... Why dont you introduce a primary key (with autovalue)? or is the field Resource unique and could become the key?

Comment: have a look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization